# How to start Chrome with flags and URL from shell script on mac osx

Tags: macos, shell, google-chrome, applescript

I want to launch Chrome with some URL and enable flags, when I launch Chrome from a shell script. I have tried the following, but am only able to achieve either enabling the flag or launching the URL. Not both together.

```
open -n /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --enable-speech-input
```

or

```
open -n /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app www.google.com
```

Both of the above commands run correctly, but when I try to do both at the same time
like the following:

```
open -n /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --enable-speech-input "www.google.com"
```

It fails. I tried using quotes but that does not work.

Comment: If Chrome is your default browser, would this work? `open http://www.google.com --args --enable-speech-input`

Comment: Your final example works fine for me as-is on Yosemite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `open`, run the Chrome executable directly from the script:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-speech-input www.google.com
```

If you have more commands to run after opening Chrome, you can open Chrome in the Background by adding the `&` character after the command (note the command is now in parenthesis):

```
(/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-speech-input www.google.com) &
```

Comment: This is somewhat related @Darrick - is there any way to configure either the app or a shortcut to automatically add those parameters without opening from terminal?